# Loaded Post Button Disable

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

how do we disable the button when all posts are loaded ?

all post loaded = button disabled or hide

or show another way ajax load more pagination codeigniter :(

I know little english sorry

**Controller**

```
public function getCountry(){
  $page =  $_GET['page'];
  $this->load->model('posts_model');
  $posts = $this->posts_model->getCountry($page);
  foreach($posts as $post){
     echo "<h3>".$post->post_title."</h3><td>".$post->post_content."</td>";
  }
  exit;
}
```

**Model**

```
public function getCountry($page){
    $offset = 2*$page;
    $limit = 2;
    $sql = "select * from posts limit $offset ,$limit";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    return $result;
}
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      getcountry(0);
      $("#load_more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).data('val');
        getcountry(page);
      });
    });

    var getcountry = function(page){
      $("#loader").show();
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/getCountry",
        type:'GET',
        data: {page:page}
      }).done(function(response){
        $("#ajax_table").append(response);
        $("#loader").hide();
        $('#load_more').data('val', ($('#load_more').data('val')+1));
        scroll();
      });
    };
    var scroll  = function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#load_more').offset().top
      }, 1000);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your get country function you can do like this. so whenever you get the empty results it means no more result available and your button will be disabled.

```
<script>

    var getcountry = function(page){
      $("#loader").show();
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/getCountry",
        type:'GET',
        dateType:'json', 
        data: {page:page}
      }).done(function(response){
        if(response.result == 'success') {
           $("#ajax_table").append(response.data);
           $("#loader").hide();
           $('#load_more').data('val', ($('#load_more').data('val')+1));
           scroll();
        } else {
           $("#load_more").prop('disabled',true);
        }
      });
    };
</script>
```

**In your controller make this changes**

```
public function getCountry(){
  $page =  $_GET['page'];
  $this->load->model('posts_model');
  $posts = $this->posts_model->getCountry($page);
  $response = array();
  $data = '';
  if(!empty($posts)) {
    foreach($posts as $post){
      $data .= "<h3>".$post->post_title."</h3><td>".$post->post_content."
            </td>";
    } 
    $response = array('result'=>'success','data'=>$data); 
  } else {
     $response = array('result'=>'error');
  }
  echo json_encode($response)
}
```

Comment: not working code
https://image.prntscr.com/image/vCErTs3AR3_MPSxQ1c6lrw.png

Comment: @Codex : It's like you are sending blank array form server so user the `json datatype`.checkout my edited answer.